# Matrix-Calculus: Expression Visualization

Tags: matrix, visualization

There is a vector matrix expression:

$q=x \cdot x^T$

Where $x$ is $3 \times 1$ vector.

I want to visualize the structure of this equation, but so far the only thing that came to my mind is to use the `ArrayPlot` command. This, of course, entails the problem of having to manually generate the vector itself. But what I need is just knowing its dimension, to visualize the elements of the expression in the form of "arrays":

[image]

**My problem is this:** And I need (if possible, without manually generating the contents of the vectors, but knowing only the dimension and expression) to build the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[x, q, a, b, c];
x = List /@ {a, b, c};
q = x . Transpose[x];

Grid[#, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {2, 2}] & /@ {x, Transpose[x], q}
```

[image]

OR

```
Grid[#, Frame -> All, 
   ItemSize -> {1, 1.3}] & /@ (ConstantArray["", 
     Dimensions@#] & /@ {x, Transpose[x], q})
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

How to accomodate: $\left.(x-y)^T.A.(x-y)\right)$

```
Clear[x, y, A]
xGrid = Grid[#, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {1, 1.5}] &@
   ConstantArray["", {3, 1}];
yGrid = Grid[#, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {1, 1.5}] &@
   ConstantArray["", {3, 1}];
AGrid = Grid[#, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {1, 1.5}] &@
   ConstantArray["", {3, 3}];
(expr = Transpose[x - y] . A . (x - y))
expr2 = TraditionalForm@expr /. {x -> xGrid, 
   y -> Overlay[{yGrid, yGrid}], A -> AGrid}
```

[image]

The hacky part is the `Overlay` that prevents the addition.

Comment: And how to build such a picture for expression: $(x-y)^T \cdot A \cdot (x-y)$  https://ibb.co/Z8brZPq where $x,y$ - $3 \times 1$, and $A$ - $3 \times 3$ ???

Comment: Your answer suits me. Thank you for your help and for not passing by the problem!

Comment: You are most welcome. Thanks for the accept.